# How to automatically assign commenter using current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new in Rails and after I made the Article model from their ([tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)) I wanted to use the Comment model but it is made up of 2 parts: The first one is where the "Commenter" inputs the name which will appear aside with the comment and the "body" of the comment.

As I am using devise and I want to skip the Commenter input so the user just inputs his/her comment and their username is automatically assigned with the comment. I have everything set up (devise, the comment model, user model etc) and also integrated the username field to the devise gem so that it works with current_user.username. I am using Rails 4

This is the code of the _comment.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Comment Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an opportunity here to mix in a parameter in your `comment_params` method, so I'd make any modifications necessary at that point.

For example:

```
params.require(...).permit(...).merge(
  commenter_id: current_user.id,
  commenter_name: current_user.name
)
```

It's *extremely* bad form for a model to have any knowledge of the state of a controller.

Comment: Totally did the trick just instead of "commenter_id" and "commenter_name" as it is just a string variable you just need to merge "commenter: current_user.username" thanks